# Attempting to number the month and year combination (1,2,3..) for each ID

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the sample data:

```
ID Month Year
1  10    2017
1  11    2017
1  12    2017
1  1     2018
2  10    2017
2  11    2017
2  12    2017
2  1     2018
```

I'd like to transform this into:

```
ID Month Year number
1  10    2017 1
1  11    2017 2
1  12    2017 3
1  1     2018 4
2  10    2017 1
2  11    2017 2
2  12    2017 3 
2  1     2018 4
```

What is the best way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df['New']=df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
df
Out[1308]: 
   ID  Month  Year  New
0   1     10  2017    1
1   1     11  2017    2
2   1     12  2017    3
3   1      1  2018    4
4   2     10  2017    1
5   2     11  2017    2
6   2     12  2017    3
7   2      1  2018    4
```